# How to write a generic variadic lambda that discards its parameters?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, variadic, unused-variables

I want to write a lambda that takes an arbitrary number of arguments by universal reference and ignores them entirely. The obvious method would be to use the syntax for a variadic universal parameter pack and omit the parameter name:

```
auto my_lambda = [](auto&&...) { return 42; };
```

This works fine (with gcc 4.9.2) until I [try to pass a non trivially-copyable object](http://goo.gl/PFux3S):

```
struct S { S() {} S(S const&) {} };
my_lambda("meow", 42, S{});
^ error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'struct S' through '...'
```

What's going on? Is my code ill-formed, or is this a bug in gcc?

In either case, what's the best workaround? I found that naming the parameter works, but then I ran into an unused-parameter warning:

```
auto my_lambda = [](auto&&... unused) { return 42; };
^ error: unused parameter 'unused#0' [-Werror=unused-parameter]
^ error: unused parameter 'unused#1' [-Werror=unused-parameter]
^ error: unused parameter 'unused#2' [-Werror=unused-parameter]
```

How do you suppress an unused-parameter warning on a template parameter pack?

Comment: That looks like a GCC bug. It [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1b37f5289b7c8ec) in 5.2.

Comment: @TartanLlama For some definition of "works". 5.2 supports passing non-trivially-copyable objects through `...`, but the parsing bug isn't fixed, IIRC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a [parsing bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64095) in GCC (which you yourself reported!). `auto&&...` is grammatically ambiguous and can be parsed as either the equivalent of `auto&&, ...` or a parameter pack declaration (technically, the question is whether `...` is part of the *parameter-declaration-clause* or the *abstract-declarator*); the standard says it's to be parsed as the latter; GCC parses it as the former.

Naming the pack resolves the parsing ambiguity:

```
auto my_lambda = [](auto&&... unused) { return 42; };
```

To suppress the warning, one could apply `__attribute__((__unused__))` (or, as @Luc Danton suggested, `[[gnu::unused]]`):

```
auto my_lambda = [](auto&&... unused __attribute__((__unused__))) { return 42; };
```

or use `sizeof...`

```
auto my_lambda = [](auto&&... unused) { (void) sizeof...(unused); return 42; };
```

Comment: Since GCC is mentioned, `type var [[gnu::unused]]` is an alternative to `type var __attribute__((__unused__))` (I forget from which version on though).

Comment: @LucDanton and eventually, `[[maybe_unused]]`.